# Is it correct to eliminate "Who are" in the below sentence?

Tags: grammar

Could you tell me grammatical point to do so by a few examples? When can we do it and when we cannot?

> People ***who are*** unhappy with their environment could simply pack up and leave.

Comment: It's needed. Or else, you can write this without 'who are' - *People, unhappy with their environment, could simply pack up and leave!*  Note the commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are dealing with in this sentence is something called a relative, restrictive clause. That type of a clause begins with a relative pronoun; in your case that is the word "who".
Other relative pronouns include that, which, whom, why...
All of them can in certain cases be omitted:

1. If the relative pronoun is the object of the relative clause

> Do you have the book **which I gave you yesterday**?

The word "which" here is the object of the sentence. Meaning that we can remove it, and still have a grammatically valid sentence.
Note: this rule does not apply to [non-restrictive clauses](http://grammar-monster.com/glossary/non-restrictive_clauses.htm).

> Do you have the book I gave you yesterday?

2. If the predicate of the relative clause contains the auxiliary verb "to be"

> People **who are unhappy with their environment** could simply pack up and
>   leave.

The predicate of this relative clause is "are unhappy"

In this case omitting both the relative pronoun and the auxiliary verb to be will give you a valid sentence, and the subject complement of the relative clause (in your case "unhappy") remains in the new sentence, which is completely grammatically correct.
Note: this rule applies to non-restrictive clauses too

> People unhappy with their environment could simply pack up and leave.

Comment: Leaving out the relative pronoun has always been common in spoken English. Since the 1970's its usage in written English is increasing steadily. Generally, the sentence is easier to parse if you do include the relative pronoun.

Comment: One way this particular sentence could be shortened is like this: _Unhappy people could simply pack up and leave_. If the sentence **must** include the "with their environment" part, then I agree with @JavaL – the "who are" may not be needed, but I'd still recommend it.